# Scoring from input in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, programming

Can you help me please?
I have a task. I have from input some text with numbers. For example:

```
beta     1
score   9
something   2
beta     4
something   1
```

I need to calculate all numbers with the same text around. And my output will be:(in this way with ":")

```
beta:5
something:3
score:9
```

Also it can be problem with temp files, where i can save my scores. And I need to use `mktemp` after script finished to delete it.
Help me please, thanks.

Comment: Which part of this is it that you have issues with? Without knowing what you think is hard, it is difficult to give a helpful answer. I don't quite understand what you mean when you talk about temporary files. `mktemp` _creates_ a file, it does not delete anything.  Also, it seems that there is no need for temporary files to solve this exercise.

Comment: @Kusalananda , I'm not sure, but i think that I need to create temp files for saving my actual scores and after my script is finished, i need delete it.

Comment: @Kusalananda , I have issues with algorithm , how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be assuming that the input will always contain exactly two fields per line.

You may use the GNU `datamash` utility to sort the data, group it by the first field, and calculate the sum of the second field for each group:

```bsh
datamash -s -W --output-delimiter=: groupby 1 sum 2 <file
```

Here, the `-s` sorts the input, `-W` makes the utility treat any run of consecutive whitespace characters as a field delimiter, and `--output-delimiter=:` sets the output delimiter to the `:` character.  The rest tells `datamash` to group by the first field and to calculate the sum of the second field for each group.

Given the input in the question in the file called `file`, this would produce the following output:

```
beta:5
score:9
something:3
```

---

You can solve this in any number of other ways too.  The easiest computational solution would be to use `awk`:

```bsh
awk '{ sum[$1] += $2 } END { for (key in sum) printf "%s:%d\n", key, sum[key] }' file
```

Here, we use an associative array, `sum`, to hold the sum for each of the strings in the first field.  The `END` block executes at the end of the input and outputs the calculated sums together with the strings.

Note that this solution also assumes that the first field is a single word containing no whitespace characters, as shown in the question.

---

Using a shell loop, reading the sorted lines from the original file, printing and resetting the sum of the second field whenever a new first field is encountered:

```bsh
unset -v prev

sort file |
{
        while read -r key value; do
                if [ "$key" != "${prev-$key}" ]; then
                        # prev is set and different from $key

                        printf '%s:%d\n' "$prev" "$sum"
                        sum=0
                fi

                prev=$key
                sum=$(( sum + value ))
        done

        if [ "${prev+set}" = set ]; then
                printf '%s:%d\n' "$prev" "$sum"
        fi
}
```

Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: There also way to solve it without awk by writing whole algorithm?

Comment: But thank u so much!

Comment: @lolilaliaa I'm afraid that I don't understand what "the whole algorithm" is that is _not_ implemented by that `awk` program (or, for that matter, encapsulated by the `datamash` command).  You may possibly have to update your question if you have further clarifications to it.

Comment: I want to say, that is that exist solution in a whole Bash language with loops, if/else and etc. I hope you understand me

Comment: @lolilaliaa Using shell loops to parse data is fragile and not usually what you want to do.  See for example [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: Ok, but this is my task do it with shell loops. But thanks :)

Comment: @lolilaliaa In that case, this should be mentioned in the question. Currently you don't say anything about that.

Comment: @lolilaliaa See updated answer.

Comment: Thank u so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with large file, consider using `sort` and `awk` so that we don't allocate huge array for storing key and values in the RAM.

```
λ cat input.txt 
beta     1
score   9
something   2
beta     4
something   1
```

```bsh
sort input.txt |
  awk -v OFS=: 'NR==1{ key=$1 }; NR>1&&$1!=key{ print key, sum; sum=0; key=$1 }; {sum+=$2} END{ print key, sum}'
```

```
beta:5
score:9
something:3
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -i SECOND
while read first second; do
        if [ -z $FIRST ] || [ $first = $FIRST ]; then
                SECOND+=second
        else 
                echo $FIRST:$SECOND
                SECOND=second
        fi
        FIRST=$first
done < <(sort file)
echo $FIRST:$SECOND
```

*Usually I write a similar blank and in production I put all the variables in quotes.*

Answer (score -1):

```
 for k in $(awk '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}' file.txt); do awk -v k="$k" 'BEGIN{sum=0}$0 ~ k {sum=sum+$2}END{print k,sum}' file.txt; done
```

output

```
beta 5
score 9
something 3
```

Comment: That's an O(n²) solution - for _n_ records it will take around _n_ reads of `file.txt`, comprising _n_*_n_ lines of data. For comparison all the other solutions are O(n). Obviously for a homework exercise such as this with small values of _n_ (lines in the file) there'll be little difference, but for a larger file such as a 1000 lines, your solution would read the entire file of 1000 lines up to 1001 times.